# Uses of components() functions in kotlin array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Why there are component#() methods in arrays in kotlin while we can use indices?

Although, their implementations are using get(index), so why do they exist?

Answer (score 4):

`component#()` methods are used for [Destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations)

```
val arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val (a, b, c) = arr // a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why there are component#() methods in arrays in kotlin while we can use indices?

They are there to enable the destructuring declaration on an array.

**e.g.**

```kotlin
val array = arrayOf("First element", "Second element", "Third element")
val (first, _, third) = array
// Prints "First element".
println(first)
// Prints "Third element".
println(third)
```